# exactextractr in R , Error: [names<-] incorrect number of names

Tags: r, r-sf, r-raster

Used [exactextractr package (CRAN link)](https://cran.r-project.org/package=exactextractr) already and it always worked : I have a raster stack (s) and cut out with a shape-file (INV) like this

```
df1 <- exact_extract(s, INV, fun = c("mean", "min", "max", "median", "variance"), append_cols = c("FLIK"))
```

But as from today I have an error message constantly like

> Error: [names<-] incorrect number of names

When I list names either of `names(s)` or `names(INV)` I cannot see any mistake.

Are there any hidden names I cannot see ? Is there alimit of names ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you have some data you can share, please feel free to open an issue at https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I manage to fix my code in a simple way. When I read the raster file (.nc), I used the `stack` function from `raster` library. This code ruturns a RasterStack object. The code below gave me the same error as you mentioned.

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)

# Reading shapefile data
shapefile<- sf::st_read("PATH_TO_SHAPEFILE")

# Reading raster data
raster <- raster::stack("PATH_TO_RASTER")

# Using exact_extract function from exactextractr package
df <- exact_extract(raster , shapefile, 'mean')
```

I managed to fix that by using the `brick` function, from the same library, that returns a RasterBrick. That way, I could run my code without errors, as following:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)

# Reading shapefile data
shapefile<- sf::st_read("PATH_TO_SHAPEFILE")

# Reading raster data
raster <- raster::brick("PATH_TO_RASTER")

# Using exact_extract function from exactextractr package
df <- exact_extract(raster , shapefile, 'mean')
```

I don't exactly knows what is happening here, because I have used the `stack` function in the past with no problem at all. For some reason, using `brick` fixed my code this time. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score -1):

It was about the fact, that there are more than one layers/channels in a tiff. First you have to reduce to one layer, then it gives the correct number of names.